# How to download files from my list with wget and ftp

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ftp, wget

I need to download only defined files with wget and ftp.
For example:

1.I retrieve all files using:

```
echo ls -R | ftp ftp://user:password@host > ./list.txt
```

2.Then I will parse the result and get a list with absolute paths for each file:

```
/path/to-the/file-1
/path/to-the/file-2
etc.
```

3.And now I need to download all files from the result list using wget and ftp.

And I don't want to create a separate FTP session for each file download process.

Please give your advice. Thank you.

Update:

For recursive download I'm using it: `wget -r ftp://user:password@host:/ -nH -P /download/path`. It works great, but I need to pass a file with a list of remote files for downloading via FTP with one FTP session.

Comment: `mkdir downloaded; wget -P ./downloaded -i SelectedFiles.txt`

Comment: @MarkSetchell In this case SelectedFiles.txt will contain URL in each string with user and password. For example:     ftp://user:password@host:/my/file/path. Am I right? But what about one FTP session for the process?

Comment: For recursive download I'm using it: `wget -r ftp://user:password@host:/ -nH -P /download/path`. It works great, but I need to pass a file with a list of remote files for downloading via FTP with one FTP session

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, I missed the *"single session"* part when I commented. I think you need to have your script generate a second script to run a single FTP session.

So, your script will not do any FTP itself, it will just write another script that does the transfers. So, it will write a script that does this

```
ftp -n <SOMEADDRESS> <<EOS
quote USER <USERNAME>
quote PASS <PASSWORD>
bin
get file1 localname1
get file2 localname2
...
get fileN localnameN
quit    
EOS
```

Then it will execute that script, by doing:

```
bash < thatScript
```

So your script will look like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
ScriptName=funkyFTPer
cat - <<END > $ScriptName
ftp -n 192.168.0.1 <<EOS
quote USER freddy
quote PASS frog
END

# Your selection code goes here ***PHNQZ***
echo get file1 localname1 >> $ScriptName
echo get file2 localname2 >> $ScriptName
echo get fileN localnameN >> $ScriptName

echo quit >> $ScriptName
echo EOS  >> $ScriptName
echo "Now run bash < $ScriptName"
```

Then delete the script as it contains your password. Or you can put the password in your `.netrc` file.

As regards creating directories locally, you can do that in the first script using `mkdir -p`. The `-p` has the advantage that it creates all directories in between in one go and doesn't get upset if they already exist.

So, just looking at the area of code where it says `***PHNQZ***` above, let's say your code decides you need file `freddy/frog/c.txt`, you could do:

```
remotename="freddy/frog/c.txt"  
localdir=${remotename%/*}         # Get just directory part using "bash Parameter Substitution"
mkdir -p "$localdir"              # make directory and all parts in between
```

Comment: Thank you very much. But I have another question about FTP. As I understand when my local directory does not exist when I call `get file1 localname1` I will receive an error about directory existence of the localname1. What can I do with it?

Comment: If you do `get /a/b/c.txt` you must have created `/a/b` on your local machine. If you do `get /a/b/c.txt c.txt` it will just copy the remote file to your current working directory and name it simply `c.txt` without your needing to have `/a/b` locally.

Comment: How can I check path existence and create needed directory with subdirectories with your script? I need a solution with recursive download. What do you think is the best way?

Comment: I have added some more at the end of my answer.

Comment: Mark, thank you. You saved me a lot of time. And can you give me an advice how can I control the state of files to download. For example if connection was lost while downloading with `echo get file1 localname1 >> $ScriptName`. I need to download the file again without starting it again for all the files.

Comment: Please have a look at `left` - that can restart failed transfers, and also has a `mirror` option. https://linux.die.net/man/1/lftp

Comment: So I need to use lftp instead of ftp in my case? And also in your script?

Comment: Not really. I meant that if you want to do restarts and more complicated things, a bash script is probably not the way to go. Either find and use a tool like `lftp` and work out how to make it do what you want, or use a more capable interpreter like `Perl` which can hold an FTP connection open whilst checking file sizes locally and remotely at the same time.

Comment: Or, in your script, where you are deciding which files to download, check if they exist locally and have the same size and a later time of modification, and if they are a different size, or older, locally, get them - else skip them. Then if your FTP hangs up, you can just re-run your script and t will skip whatever it has already done.

Comment: Now i'm testing your solution and i have a question about exit code. When i try this: `bash < funkyFTPer ; echo $?` It returns 0 even when I have user and password errors. How can I get real exit code of the funkyFTPer example?

Comment: Try adding `exit $?` as the last line in `funkyFTPer`. You may need to execute it differently, so instead of `bash < funkyFTPer`, you may need to do `chmod +x funkyFTPer; ./funkyFTPer`